# Update field with value according to occurence

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following problem: I would like to update a Access table with a value. The value should be added if multiple conditions are true.

- If a value in column A exists more than once AND
- If a value in column B exists more than once AND
- If column C is not empty

I tried it with the following query, which almost works but seems to ignore the condition on column B. For example, there are three records. Those three have the same value in "a" but only two of them have the same value in "b". Still, the query writes "f" for all three of them.

```
UPDATE table1 SET a = "f"  
WHERE a IN (SELECT a FROM table1 GROUP BY a, b HAVING COUNT(a) > 1) 
AND b IN (SELECT b FROM table1 GROUP BY a, b HAVING COUNT(b) > 1) AND [c] <> " ";
```

It could be doable with VBA (Looping through everything) but I want to avoid that. And I really want to know why it does not work.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think your `group by` conditions are wrong.  Based on your description:

```
UPDATE table1
    SET a = "f"  
WHERE a IN (SELECT a FROM table1 GROUP BY a HAVING COUNT(a) > 1) AND
      b IN (SELECT b FROM table1 GROUP BY b HAVING COUNT(b) > 1) AND
      c <> " ";
```

Comment: Unfortunately, changing it to this simply ignores the "has to have more than one occurence" condition and just focuses on the "not empty" condition.

Comment: The third condition is the "not empty" condition on `c`.